# Slow internet on 1 device and only on certain wifi connections

Tags: wireless-networking, performance

In my house I have a cable modem, which provides wifi, and a separate router, plugged into that modem, which also provides wifi.  Due to historical reasons, most of the devices in my house connect to the router's wifi but either is available and both work equally well.

Of those devices, one laptop has super slow internet access - less than 1mb/sec download according to Internet Speed Test while another laptop will get around 20.  That slow laptop gets the same results regardless of which of those 2 wifis it is connected to.

If I make my cell phone a hot spot and provided a 3rd, yet not-associated-with-the-others, wifi connection, that slow laptop will have fast internet access - >20Mb/sec download and operates quite nicely.

Question - What gives?  If it is the Network adapter then wouldn't it be the same regardless of 3 wifi connections?  The slowness is the same regardless of browser - both Chrome and Edge show the same results. So its not a browser issue, right?  Its not the routers nor the internet service since the other devices have no issue, right?

I have googled the problem and found a variety of search results that deal with the slowness but not found any that state the additional non-slowness when connected to a completely different internet access point.

I am really confused here on which way to attack this and am hoping someone here can help.

Thanks,
Randy

Comment: One thing to consider is some sort of incompatibility between your wireless (I assume your wireless setups are similar) and the wireless adapter of the slow laptop.  Are you able to try a USB wireless adapter?

Comment: what is the connection speed and type between laptop and router? is the other laptop in the same room? on 802.11b it can get down to 1Mb/s if low signal or more interference. other electrical appliances can also affect the speed.

Comment: @John - Are you saying an incompatibility between the router and the laptop's wireless adapter?  If so, there is the same slowness when connected to either wireless network.  I would think the same wireless adapter would be used when connecting to my phone which is not slow.  To me, that seems to remove the adapter as being suspect.  Unless I am missing something

Comment: @Zina - How would I check connection speed between the laptop and the router?  (I'll google it).  At the moment, not in the same room but have been before and the problem existed.  I have used my laptop in the same room where her's is having problem and had no issues with mine.  On her laptop the signal strength is good.

Comment: Are you saying an incompatibility between the router and the laptop's wireless adapter?    <-- I think that is a possibility. This laptop works fine via cell phone hookup.

Answer (score 0):

The issue you could be facing could be one of several problems. The first being that your old laptop's wireless setup is not incompatible with your router (and modem) but not your phone. Perhaps your phone has more up to date compatibility. To diagnose this, as @John said, you should try a USB wireless adapter with your old computer.

Another issue could be that the laptop wireless adapter isn't strong enough to pick up the router's wifi signal and has to slow down the connection to compensate. This would explain when you have your phone set up, the connection is fast as the phone is acting like a wifi booster. Try bringing your laptop right beside the router and see if anything changes. (Trying the last step of using a USB wireless adapter will also solve this issue)

Some other areas of fault could be the router settings itself (less likely as the issue shows on both wireless networks). It is possible that accidentally the bandwidth cap was set to 1Mb/sec for your laptop. To test this, you have a couple options which depends on your network setup. Firstly you will want to log into your router settings and check what settings have been set up for each device (every router is different so you'll have to check your user manual for that). Alternatively, one could set random hardware addresses (MAC addresses) and trick your router into thinking you are a new PC and see what happens. Lastly, it could also be helpful to reset both wireless networks and see if that helps.

If all this fails, then the problem most likely is software related. The computer could limit network traffic when connected to your phone's hot spot as it knows they often use data (I believe Windows 10 has a feature like this built in) but when you connect to the router, it lets unlimited traffic through. Hypothetically an application could be running the background and hogging all your network resources. To check this, go to task manager and see if anything is chocking up the network adapter. Remember speedtests can only measure what is available to them and if another program is using most of the system resources, they couldn't check that for you.

I hope this is helpful.

Comment: Don't believe the laptop is *that old* but will certainly try the USB adapter and see what happens.  Worth a try.  Just need to get one.  Not thinking it is a strength problem as it will do the same when in the same room as the router.  But will try placing it closer to see what happens.  I'll check the cap also.  When you say 'reset both wireless networks'... I have done cold boots (unplugged and plugged the power) if that is what you mean.  I did check the Task Manager but didn't see anything unusual.  Thanks for the suggestions.  Got some things to try this week.  I'll post back later.

Comment: To diagnose what is going wrong, it could be helpful to perform a "hard reset" of the router and modem which is usually done by holding down the reset button (every router is slightly different). The reset will set the router to its factory settings after which you will need to set it back up. This will eliminate any settings being changed or issues on the router end. Best of luck!

Answer (score 0):

well, not sure I got a resolution to this.  I received an Oculus VR headset for Christmas and was having issues when casting it to my Chromecast.  I found that upgrading the router to a WiFi6 would help.  As mentioned in my original question - I have a router connected to my cable company modem which also provides a wifi endpoint and regardless of which wifi endpoint the laptop was connected to it would always be super slow (around 2 Mbps).  With the new router, connected to the modem and on that same laptop, I now get 100+Mbps.  Odd thing is, when connected to the modem's wifi I still get super slow speed.  {shoulder shrug} I dunno.